# How to fix: This use of org/hibernate/Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query; can be vulnerable to SQL/HQL injection

Tags: java, hibernate, sonarqube

I have this ProductDao.java class:

```
@Repository(value = "ProductDao")
public class ProductDao implements IProductDao {
    
    public static final String LABEL_LIKE = "labellike";
    
    public static final String NUM_CODE = "n_code";
    
    public static final String LABEL = "label";
    
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    
    public Query createQuery(String query) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
    }
    
    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductSelectQuery() {
        StringBuilder select = new StringBuilder();
        select.append("SELECT distinct mp ");
        
        return select;
    }

    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductCountQuery() {
        StringBuilder count = new StringBuilder();
        count.append("SELECT Count (distinct mp) ");
        
        return count;
    }

    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductJoinQuery(CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {
        StringBuilder join = new StringBuilder();

        join.append(" FROM MasterProduct AS mp");
        join.append(" JOIN mp.products AS p");
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getNomenclatureCode())
                || getSortFieldLevel(catalogFilter.getSortField()) != 0) {
            join.append(" JOIN mp.nomenclature AS n");
        }
        join.append(" LEFT JOIN p.family AS f");
        if ("productLifeVO".equals(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            join.append(" LEFT JOIN mp.productLife AS pl ");
        }
        return join;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductClauseQuery(CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {
        StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();     
        // WHERE
                clause.append(" WHERE 1=1");
                if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getNomenclatureCode()) ){
                    clause.append(" AND n.value LIKE :n_code");
                }
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getTextSearch())) {
                    clause.append(" AND (mp.partnerProductReference like :labellike");
                    clause.append(" OR mp.name like :labellike");
                    clause.append(" OR mp.shortDescription like :labellike");
                    clause.append(" OR f.keywords like :labellike");
                    clause.append(")");
                }
                if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getProductStatus()) ) {
                clause.append(" AND p.status = :status ");
                }
        
        return clause;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductOrderByNomenClature(CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {
        
        StringBuilder orderByP2 = new StringBuilder();
        if (NOMENCLATURE_ONE.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            orderByP2.append(" ORDER BY n.parent.parent.parent.parent.label");
        }
        if (NOMENCLATURE_TWO.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            orderByP2.append(" ORDER BY n.parent.parent.parent.label");

        }
        if (NOMENCLATURE_THREE.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            orderByP2.append(" ORDER BY  n.parent.parent.label");

        }
        if (NOMENCLATURE_FOUR.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            orderByP2.append(" ORDER BY  n.parent.label");

        }
        if (NOMENCLATURE_FIVE.equalsIgnoreCase(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            orderByP2.append(" ORDER BY  n.label");

        }
        orderByP2.append(" ").append(catalogFilter.getSortOrder());
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getTextSearch())) {
                orderByP2.append(", ");
            }
            
        return orderByP2;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductOrderByTextSearch(CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {
        
        StringBuilder orderByTxtSearch = new StringBuilder();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            orderByTxtSearch.append(" ORDER BY ");
        }
        orderByTxtSearch.append(" CASE WHEN (mp.partnerProductReference like :labellike) THEN 1");
        orderByTxtSearch.append(" WHEN (mp.name like :labellike) THEN 2");
        orderByTxtSearch.append(" WHEN (f.keywords like :labellike) THEN 3");
        orderByTxtSearch.append(" WHEN (mp.shortDescription like :labellike) THEN 4");
        orderByTxtSearch.append(" END");
        orderByTxtSearch.append(" , CASE WHEN (instr(mp.name, :label)>0) THEN instr(mp.name, :label) END ");

        return orderByTxtSearch;
    }
    
    private StringBuilder paginatedListMasterProductOrderByAllFieldQuery(CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {

        StringBuilder orderBy = new StringBuilder();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getSortField())) {
            if (get(catalogFilter.getSortField()) != null) {
                orderBy.append(paginatedListMasterProductOrderByNameAndPubliStock(catalogFilter));
            } else if (getSortFieldLevel(catalogFilter.getSortField()) != 0) {
                orderBy.append(paginatedListMasterProductOrderByNomenClature(catalogFilter));
            }

        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getTextSearch())) {
            orderBy.append(paginatedListMasterProductOrderByTextSearch(catalogFilter));
        }

        return orderBy;
    }
    
    private void setParameterQuery(Query query, Query countQuery,CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {
        // SET PARAMETERS
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getTextSearch())) {
            query.setParameter(LABEL_LIKE, '%' + catalogFilter.getTextSearch() + '%');
            query.setParameter(LABEL, catalogFilter.getTextSearch());
            countQuery.setParameter(LABEL_LIKE, '%' + catalogFilter.getTextSearch() + '%');
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getNomenclatureCode())) {
            query.setParameter(NUM_CODE, catalogFilter.getNomenclatureCode() + "%");
            countQuery.setParameter(NUM_CODE, catalogFilter.getNomenclatureCode() + "%");
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(catalogFilter.getProductStatus())) {
            if (catalogFilter.getProductStatus().equals(Product.ProductStatus.ACTIVE.toString())) {
                query.setParameter(STATUS, Product.ProductStatus.ACTIVE);
                countQuery.setParameter(STATUS, Product.ProductStatus.ACTIVE);
            }else {
                query.setParameter(STATUS, Product.ProductStatus.INACTIVE);
                countQuery.setParameter(STATUS, Product.ProductStatus.INACTIVE);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public MasterProduct checkDuplicateOrangeReference(String orangeReference) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SELECT mp ");
        sb.append("FROM MasterProduct As mp ");
        sb.append("WHERE mp.orangeProductReference =:orangeReference ");

        Query query = createQuery(sb.toString());
        query.setParameter("orangeReference", orangeReference);
        return find(query);
    }

    @Override
    public List<MasterProduct> getAllMasterProductsByNomenclatureCode(CatalogFilterVO catalogFilter) {
        StringBuilder select = paginatedListMasterProductSelectQuery();
        StringBuilder join = paginatedListMasterProductJoinQuery(catalogFilter);
        StringBuilder clause = paginatedListMasterProductClauseQuery(catalogFilter);
        StringBuilder orderBy = paginatedListMasterProductOrderByAllFieldQuery(catalogFilter);
        StringBuilder count = paginatedListMasterProductCountQuery();

        String queryString = new StringBuilder().append(select).append(join).append(clause).append(orderBy).toString();
        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
        Query countQuery = createQuery(new StringBuffer().append(count).append(join).append(clause).toString());

        setParameterQuery(query, countQuery, catalogFilter);

        return query.list();
    }
}

On line Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
```

I got this sonarqube vulnerability issue:  This use of org/hibernate/Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query; can be vulnerable to SQL/HQL injection (with Hibernate)

how to fix my vulnerability ? I am using hibernate parameter binding and set values within setParameterQuery.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a public method which takes the String parameter as query, that's why it is complaining.

You need to restrict the query to be something which is not freely to choose from the outside.

Comment: Yes it is getAllMasterProductsByNomenclatureCode method which causes the problem, but I used hibernate parameter binding, can you precise me what to restrict?

Comment: change the method access modifier to **private** Query createQuery(String query).

Comment: for the metyod createQuery, it is public within my Dao just to show its content, however, it is a method within parent Dao.

Comment: but that's exactly what the issue is about. there is a public accessible method which takes an arbitrary String and using it directly as query. it was also not clear that it is in the interface defined, because it does not have the @Override annotation.

Comment: you just misunderstanding what I've said, the method is within parent interface, I've just copied it their to let people see its content, I see nothing wrong on it